# I'm trying to pull data from database where the data will be pulled from two different tables in the db,error is in $returns = mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to pull data from two different tables in the database and I keep on having error. when I run the code it displays nothing

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$st="";
$sc="";

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "submit"){
       $st=$_POST['s-t'];
       $sc= "WHERE nums like \"%$st%\"  or d_n like \"%st%\" ";
    }


    if (isset ($_GET['look']) && $_GET ['look'] != "") {
       $st=$_GET['look'];
       $sc = "WHERE nums like \"%$st%\"  or d_n like \"%st%\" ";
     }

    $db = mysql_db_connect();
    $rpp = 50;

    if (isset($_GET['page'])){

    $pn = $_GET['page'];
    $begin = ($rpp*$pn)-$rpp;
    $finish=($rpp*$pn);
    $finish=50;
} 
else {
    $pn =1;
    $begin = 0;
    $finish =$rpp;
} 

    $returns = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM  extenz $sc", $db);
    $numer_rows = mysql_num_rows($returns);
    $number_pages = ((int) ($numer_rows/$rpp)) +1;

    if (($number_rows % rpp) ==0){
    $number_pages=$number_pages -1;
}
$returns = mysql_query("SELECT nums, name , p_m FROM extenz, P_exten  left join p_exten on extenz $sc order by nums & P_m LIMIT $begin, $finish", $db);

?>
```

Comment: we don't see your db connection function. you need to check if you really connect to the database. if you confirm that connection is ok then output your SQL string before $returns lines and check your sql string. There might be many things wrong - and actually you should not be using mysql_ functions in the first place - anymore.

Comment: of course the actual error you forgot to tell us should say a lot as well.

Comment: Is there an error or just no results? The indenting of this code makes it hard to read, you should edit it so the indentations are correct.

Comment: yes i did check the db connection and it works. the error is in the following line : $returns = mysql_query("SELECT nums, name , p_m FROM extenz, P_exten  left join p_exten on extenz $sc order by nums & P_m LIMIT $begin, $finish", $db);

Comment: That's not valid SQL / MySQL syntax.

Comment: `SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;`

Answer (score 0):

i answered my  question

the error was in the following line of code

```
$returns = mysql_query("SELECT nums, name , p_m FROM extenz, P_exten  left join p_exten on extenz $sc order by nums & P_m LIMIT $begin, $finish", $db);
```

and the correction was

```
$returns = mysql_query("SELECT extenz.nums, extenz.name,p_exten.P_M FROM extenz LEFT JOIN ON  p_exten.extenz=extenz.nums $sc ORDER BY nums LIMIT $begin, $finish",$db);
```